# Native ActionBar to ActionBarSherlock Migration

Tags: android

Is there a guide for migrative Native ActionBar (API 11) to ActionBarSherlock?
My app already has actionbar implemented but now I wish to migrate to ActionBAr Sherlock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Add the ActionBarSherlock JAR to the `libs/` directory of your project.

Step #2: Have your activities (or the whole application) use a Sherlock-flavored theme (e.g., `Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`)

Step #3: Change all your activities to inherit from their Sherlock-flavored equivalents (e.g., `Activity` -> `SherlockActivity`, `ListActivity` -> `SherlockListActivity`)

Step #4: Change all your fragments to inherit from their Sherlock-flavored equivalents (e.g., `Fragment` -> `SherlockFragment`, `ListFragment` -> `SherlockListFragment`)

Step #5: Change all calls to `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`

Step #6: Fix up any other imports as needed (e.g., `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will now need the Sherlock's implementation of `Menu` instead of Android's)

And that should just about do it. You will already have `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 11 or higher, courtesy of your existing native action bar implementation, so that step is taken care of for you.

Comment: @geeknizer: Manual action modes can also be converted, using a similar process, though I haven't done that recently and cannot readily enumerate the steps. However, ActionBarSherlock does not support `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`, because that's tied too tightly to the native API Level 11 implementation of `ListView`.

Comment: I made through all of it, only thing which doesn't have an equivalent is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html In original impl, it was popupMenu.getMenu() which is android.view.Menu